# What is a good alternative to Unix time for encoding date of birth?

Tags: json, date, datetime, unix-timestamp

I would like to use unix time for date of birth, but it doesn't work so well for date of birth because Unix time starts in 1970.

I'll be sending the date of birth as JSON. Does it make sense to use Unix time with negative numbers? Or is there another standard that works better?

This is for an API, working with multiple clients, so I want to use a standard, simple convention. YYYYMMDD seems confusing and error prone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The International Organization for Standardization (ISO) advocates `YYYY-MM-DD`.

The World Wide Web Consortium (W3C)'s Quality Assurance Interest Group (QAIG) comments:

> Albeit not perfect, ISO date format is, however, the best choice for a date representation that is universally (and accurately) understandable. [[link](http://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/iso-date)]

And I think most technically-minded people will recognize it.